# I need help to make the last part of my query, It isn't performatic so it won't work for much time

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to make an old procedure more performatic, so I decided to create a helper table with the values I need to compare, but one of the values I need to compare is a complex object instead of just ids, right now I'm stuck on the cultural fit calculation of my query.
This calculation is based on table TenantFit, where I have the target value, and the column I created on the new table for it is the fitCultural column of candidateDescription

Table TenantFit

| idCategory | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 96.00 |
| 17 | 85.00 |
| 18 | 98.00 |
| 19 | 96.00 |
| 20 | 94.00 |
| 21 | 91.00 |

Table CandidateDescription

| idCandidate | Specialitites | SoftSkills | fitCultural |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | [1,2,3] | ["04ee0bc5-6abb-4b4a-ab37-f69e46d8de3c", "0cbc7281-6244-4c2a-8b5e-09fe0ca81d73"] | [{"score": 75.00, "idCategory": 16}, {"score": 62.50, "idCategory": 17}, {"score": 12.50,"idCategory": 20}, {"score": 81.25, "idCategory": 21}, {"score": 43.75, "idCategory": 18},{"score": 100.00, "idCategory": 19}] |

from

```
cross join JSON_TABLE(t.fitCultural, '$[*]' COLUMNS( score INT PATH '$.score', idCategory int PATH '$.idCategory' ERROR ON ERROR))
```

| idCategory | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 96.00 |
| 17 | 85.00 |
| 18 | 98.00 |
| 19 | 96.00 |
| 20 | 94.00 |
| 21 | 91.00 |

The old query that calculates this on the procedure:

```
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(ABS(fitTenant.value - categoryAvg.score)) AS score,
          COUNT(fitTenant.idTenant) AS countCategories,
          categoryAvg.idGeneratedAssessment
   FROM `kula-avaliacao`.tenant_fitcultural AS fitTenant
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT if(count(aa.idGeneratedAssessment) > 0, TRUNCATE(SUM(a.score)/count(aa.idGeneratedAssessment), 2), 0) AS score,
             q.idCategory,
             aa.idGeneratedAssessment
      FROM `kula-avaliacao`.assessmentanswer aa
      INNER JOIN `kula-avaliacao`.answer a ON a.idAnswer = aa.idAnswer
      INNER JOIN `kula-avaliacao`.question q ON q.idQuestion = a.idQuestion
      GROUP BY q.idCategory,
               aa.idGeneratedAssessment) AS categoryAvg ON categoryAvg.idCategory = fitTenant.idCategory
   WHERE fitTenant.idTenant = idTenant
   GROUP BY fitTenant.idTenant,
            categoryAvg.idGeneratedAssessment) AS fitCulturalTenant ON fitCulturalTenant.idGeneratedAssessment = generatedAssessment.idGeneratedAssessment
```

How my new procedure is looking like:

```
SELECT t.*,
       TRUNCATE((count(cDps.idDiscProfile)/@totalJobSoftSkills) * 100, 2) AS AderenciaComportamental,
       TRUNCATE(100 - (fitTenant.score / fitTenant.countCategories), 2) AS CulturalFit
FROM
  (SELECT TRUNCATE(((count(ce.idVaga)/@totalJobSpecialities) * 100), 2) AS AderenciaTecnica,
          cd.*
   FROM 'kula-candidate'.candidatedescription AS cd
   INNER JOIN kula.candidato AS c ON c.idCandidato = cd.idCandidate
   LEFT JOIN kula.vagaespecialidade AS ce ON ce.idVaga = idVaga
   AND JSON_CONTAINS(cd.specialities, CAST(ce.idEspecialidade AS JSON))
   GROUP BY c.idCandidato) AS t -- Aderencia comportamental

LEFT JOIN 'kula-avaliacao'.discprofilesoftskill cDps ON cDps.idDiscProfile = @idDiscProfile
AND if(t.softSkills IS NOT NULL, JSON_CONTAINS(t.softSkills, CAST(CONCAT('"', cDps.idDiscSoftSkill, '"') AS JSON), '$'), FALSE) -- Fit cultural

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(ABS(fitTenant.value - candidateFit.score)) AS score,
          COUNT(fitTenant.idTenant) AS countCategories,
          ds.idCandidate,
          fitTenant.idTenant
   FROM 'kula-avaliacao'.tenant_fitcultural AS fitTenant
   LEFT JOIN 'kula-candidate'.candidatedescription ds ON ds.idcandidate IS NOT NULL
   LEFT JOIN JSON_TABLE(ds.fitCultural, '$[*]' COLUMNS(score INT PATH '$.score', idCategory text PATH '$.idCategory' ERROR ON ERROR)) AS candidateFit ON candidateFit.idCategory = fitTenant.idCategory
   GROUP BY fitTenant.idTenant,
            ds.idCandidate)AS fitTenant ON fitTenant.idTenant = idTenant
AND fitTenant.idCandidate = t.idCandidate
GROUP BY t.idCandidate;
```

The only solution I can come to is doing a new `left join(select...)` and I don't know if it is the best performatic solution, but it works (with a real high time waste, since we have 90k+ candidates)

```
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(ABS(fitTenant.value - candidateFit.score)) AS score,
          COUNT(fitTenant.idTenant) AS countCategories,
          ds.idCandidate,
          fitTenant.idTenant
   FROM `kula-avaliacao`.tenant_fitcultural AS fitTenant
   LEFT JOIN `kula-candidate`.candidatedescription ds ON ds.idcandidate IS NOT NULL
   LEFT JOIN JSON_TABLE(ds.fitCultural, '$[*]' COLUMNS(score INT PATH '$.score', idCategory text PATH '$.idCategory' ERROR ON ERROR)) AS candidateFit ON candidateFit.idCategory = fitTenant.idCategory
   GROUP BY fitTenant.idTenant,
            ds.idCandidate)AS fitTenant ON fitTenant.idTenant = idTenant
AND fitTenant.idCandidate = t.idCandidate
```